# Download Multiple audio file one by one using WebClient in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, webclient

I need to download some audio files located in D:/ drive on a remote server. All the files are in same folder. For Some security resign I can not provide direct download link to these files on my website (Written in ASP.NET C#).

After searching on Google and other websites I found that it can be done by the means of WebClient. Can you please show me some sample or you can point me to the right direction.

Desired files are kept outside of website.

Comment: If you setup a web site (to resolve path to D:\ instead of web site folders) AND you override default IIS security settings to allow site to read above web site root...did you consider to use FTP? Isn't much simpler?

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I can not use FTP because it does not appropriate in my case. I need to provide these download links to my android App in some cases.

Comment: Well then yes, you have to setup a site, rewrite url to map proper path and disable that security check in IIS. Clients will be able to download through a direct link, WebClient or anything else